# Regrex error now able to figure out

Tags: javascript, html

How to implement this in javascript !

```
var re =([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\+([0-9]+\/[0-9]+); 
var str="1/2,3/4"; 
str.match(re);
```

error is shown! I want to allow only two '/' for a input field accepting fractions 1/2,4/6 the next fraction should not be allowed ! Can I use pattern in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = new Regex('[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\+([0-9]+\/[0-9]+'); 
var str="1/2,3/4"; 
str.match(re);

or

str.match(/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\+([0-9]+\/[0-9]+/)
```

Please follow references https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better regex for this:

```js
let re  = /([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)/g; 
let str = "1/2,3/4";

let matches = str.match(re);

if (matches === null) {
    console.log('No matches');
} else {
    console.log(`Found ${matches.length} matches`);
}
```

This will detect fractions at any locations in a string, then you can use `matches.length` to test for the number of fractions entered.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a `regex` here? look like you are trying to get the parts around the `,`, and you will get an Array with the parts that are around the char `,`.

You can use `String.prototype.split` with the char of `,`.

```js
const str = "1/2,3/4";
console.log(str.split(','))
```